# Написание консольного приложение на C# для Android

Tags: android, c#, консоль

Здравствуйте, заинтересовался вопросом создания консольного приложения на C# для android, скажите пожалуйста, каким образом это можно сделать.

Comment: Хм, а как его там запустить?

Comment: Возможно вы имели ввиду Xamarin ?